# How to make a PCA plot using a square relationship matrix

Tags: r

I have a square relationship matrix made using:

```
data<-input[,!names(input) %in% "gene"]
data1<-t(as.matrix(data[-1])) %*% as.matrix(data[-1]) / ncol(data)
```

The matrix looks like:

```
            Sample1     Sample2     Sample3     Sample4
Sample1     9418618.2   13053118.21 10547526.06 13866574.6
Sample2     13053118.21 35073099.45 26735255.06 24575542.03
Sample3     10547526.06 26735255.06 23083477.94 19077039.18
Sample4     13866574.6  24575542.03 19077039.18 25187674.69
Sample5     9443282.04  23464046.78 26729979.61 12996476.38
```

I want to make a PCA plot of this matrix. I tried using:

```
res.pca <- prcomp(data, scale = TRUE)
summary(res.pca)
str(res.pca)
plot(res.pca$x[,1],res.pca$x[,2], xlab="PC1", ylab = "PC2", main = "PC1 / PC2 - plot11")
```

But it gives error:

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
```

Comment: You must first create a PCA object, see `help('prcomp')`.

Comment: Thank you! I have created a PCA object using res.pca <- prcomp(data1, scale = TRUE). I want to plot first two principal components.

Comment: In the help page above there is an example of `biplot`. See if this is what you are looking for.